# Why does Matcher.find() return false when run after Matcher.lookingAt()?

Tags: java, regex

I've noticed that calling `Matcher.lookingAt()` affects `Matcher.find()`. I ran `lookingAt()` in my code and it returned *true*. When I then ran `find()` so that I can start returning matches, i got *false*. If I remove the `lookingAt()` call, `find()` returns *true* and prints my matches. Does anyone know why?

**Trial1:**

```
Matcher matches = Pattern.compile("T\\d+").matcher("T234bird");
System.out.println(matches.lookingAt()); //after running this, find() will return false
while (matches.find())
    System.out.println(matches.group());
//Output: true
```

**Trial2:**

```
Matcher matches = Pattern.compile("T\\d+").matcher("T234bird");
//System.out.println(matches.lookingAt()); //without this, find() will return true
while (matches.find())
    System.out.println(matches.group());
//Output: T234
```

**Trial3:**

```
Matcher matches = Pattern.compile("T\\d+").matcher("T234bird");
while (matches.lookingAt()) 
    System.out.println(matches.group());
//Output: T234 T234 T234 T234 ... till crash
//I understand why this happens. It's not my question but I just included it in case someone may try to suggest it
```

Ultimately, what I want to achieve is: First confirm that the match is at the beginning of the string, then print it. I ended up doing:

```
Matcher matches = Pattern.compile("T\\d+").matcher("T234bird");
if(matches.lookingAt()) 
    System.out.println(matches.group());
//Output: T234
```

This solves my problem but my question is: Does anyone know why `lookingAt()` affect `find()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In trial 1, the call `lookingAt` matches `T234`, and your subsequent call to `find` starts looking for a match at the **end of the previous match**. If you want to go back to the beginning of the string you need to call [`Matcher.reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#reset%28%29). This is explained in the documentation for [Matcher.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29):

> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a
>   previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
>   not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the
>   previous match.

Note that `lookingAt` works with `start`, `end`, and `group` the same way `find` does, so you can just do this if you are only interested in the beginning of the string:

```
Matcher matches = Pattern.compile("T\\d+").matcher("T234bird");
if (matches.lookingAt())
    System.out.println(matches.group());
```

You have to use `if` instead of `while` here, because `lookingAt` always starts looking at the beginning of the string, not at the end of the previous match, so `while` just loops forever.

Answer (score 4):

The call to `.lookingAt()` matches *and consumes*  `T234`, so the following `.find()` call starts off at `bird` - a non-match.

You need to reset your matcher object in order to start at the beginning again.

Or simply use a start-of-string anchor in your regex and use `.find()` right away:

```
Matcher matches = Pattern.compile("^T\\d+").matcher("T234bird");
if (matches.find())
    System.out.println(matches.group());
```

Comment: +1 Okay, so it continues at `bird` after finding a match in `lookingAt`. I see. The `^` is a good idea too. Thanks.

Comment: +1. Now do yourself a favor and forget you ever heard of the `lookingAt()` method.  It's useful only in very rare circumstances, and it's *never* necessary.